# Need to iterate over the last two objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, conditional-statements

I have object array with values as follows,

```
{
 [ 
   {foo: a, bar: b}
 ]
}
```

I need to check if the last two value of an array object member of `foo` at least contains one 'x', so when the data is added like this,

```
{
 [ 
   {foo: a, bar: b}, 
   {foo: x, bar: d},
   {foo: e, bar: f}
 ]
}
```

it returns true,
however it returns error when the data is still empty or less than 1, since foo is undefined yet.

I tried to check with if statement like `array[length - 2].foo === 'x'? : tit() : tat()` but since it's not defined/added yet it keeps undefined.

What's the proper way to check? Weirdly I cannot trap it with `else` either

Comment: Add a check on the `length` of array before processing it.

Comment: I checked it first by `if (array[0].foo)` but still returns undefined since array[0].foo is not created yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `slice` method in order to take the last `two` elements.

```
array.slice(-2)
```

Also, use `some` method in order to check if an array object member of `foo` at least **contains** one `'x'`,

```js
let array= [{foo: 'a', bar: 'b'}, {foo: 'x', bar: 'd'}, {foo: 'e', bar: 'f'}];
console.log(array.slice(-2).some(a=>a.foo=='x'));
array=[];
console.log(array.slice(-2).some(a=>a.foo=='x'));
```

Comment: so when the array is empty it returns false and not undefined?

Comment: @Ardhi, it returns false. Have a look to updated answer.